# How to retrieve last six months data from database and group monthly data

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to fetch last 6 months data from database and display the data separated monthly. In my case I want to fetch last 6 month data, group them by their respective month and display in a graph month wise in a morris bar graph.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: not possible without a table definition and some sample data

Comment: I have a table 'dynamicorders' with some columns including order date and other related data. The query below gives me last month data. I can also get last six months data by dynamically declaring the date intervals.
But how can I can group the data depending upon their months? For example I want to display number of customers for the month of August, July, June ...... March. `SELECT product_name, customers,sum('order_total') as sales FROM dynamicorders WHERE order_status='Shipped' AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE( order_date, '%m/%d/%Y' )) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) `

Comment: There's this amazing invention. There are some web sites where you can type phrases like **mysql group data by month** into a text box. These web sites look at the *whole internet* and give you suggestions for things to read.  Seriously, I downvoted this question because it's very frequently asked and answered in one form or another.

Comment: Thanks for your concerns, there is no harm in asking questions though.

Comment: @OllieJones , also looks like a  [RTFM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) but I vote to close because too broad (bar grahp part)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81776/1

```
create table dynamicorders (
  order_date date,
  order_total int,
  order_status char(10)
  );

insert into dynamicorders values( '2015-07-05', 705, 'Shipped'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2015-07-15', 715, 'Shipped'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2015-08-02', 802, 'Shipped'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2015-08-12', 812, 'Closed'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2015-08-29', 829, 'Shipped'); 
insert into dynamicorders values( '2015-09-03', 903, 'Shipped'); 


SELECT 
Month(order_date) as month, 
sum(order_total) as sales 
FROM dynamicorders 
WHERE 
order_status='Shipped' 
GROUP BY Month(order_date);
```

(if the orders are the same year, otherwise you need to take care of previous years too, as month july can be 2015, 2014 ... etc)

Comment: Appreciated. I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to group data sets from last six month compared to the current month so previous year will not be a problem.